# Can we use Face Tracking on Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, biometrics, face-id

So basically the Delegation method `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?` aren't called on Swift Playgrounds.
 I'm using an iPad Pro 11 (with Truedepth frontal-camera).
 I tried to run the same code on Xcode, and I got it!
But on Swift Playground I did not succeed.

[image: I'm using this code]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Never include code as a screenshot in your question, [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text using proper code formatting. Code from a picture cannot be copied to be tested and isn't searchable.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No, since you cannot run a playground on a real device and ARKit doesn't support the simulator.